# Grease Pencil Randomize is grayed out

Tags: grease-pencil

In draw mode in grease pencil, in strokes in the randomize section, hue and the other ones are grayed out, how do I fix that?[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch to vertex color mode. In material mode (the one you were in), the color of the stroke points is defined by the material and can't be randomized individually.

In vertex color mode each stroke point can have its own color. And can therefore be randomized.

[image]